# Click a button in HTML to submit MySQL query, change background, and disable button

Tags: php, mysql, html, css

On my site users can search for different foods, and in the search results I have a little plus symbol that adds that food to their account. I want to make it so when the plus is clicked, a database query is run that adds the food to their account, changes the background of the button to a checkmark (giving them feedback that they clicked the button), and disable the button so they can't add that food again.

Comment: So do you have an actual question, or are you experiencing problems? Have you tried anything? Or are you just asking someone to write your code for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<style>
.before
{
    background:url('plus.jpg'); 
}

.after
{
    background:url('tick.jpg');     
}
</style>        

    <script>
function add_food()
{   
jQuery.ajax({       
      url: 'addfood.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {'id':jQuery('#food_item').val()},
      success: function(html) {
        jQuery('#button').removeClass('before');
        jQuery('#button').addClass('after');
        jQuery('#button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      }, 
      error: function() {
        jQuery('#error').html('<div>Error! Unable to add food item.</div>');
      }
    });
}
</script>

<input type="hidden" value="food_id" id="food_item" />
<input id="button" type="button" class="before" onclick="add_food();" />
```

I hope that make sense and should atleast get you started

Comment: Do not forget to use chaining. For example, in success callback: jQuery('#button').removeClass('before').addClass('after').attr('disabled', 'disabled')